# Any Problem With Two PMOS Sources Tied Together?

Tags: switches

This is my third revision of this supply switching circuit. Do you guys see any problem with this revision?

This is a circuit to switch from disposable lithium battery to USB power when the device is plugged into a computer. Q1 and Q2 are PFETs. When there's no USB power, both FETs Vgs is -3.6v. When USB is plugged in, the USB interface IC sends 3.3v to the FETs gates, sufficiently turning Q1 and Q2 off. VBUS is a regulated voltage from USB. The diode to is keep from back feeding the regulator when there's no USB power.

I can't use an ORing diode circuit, I cant afford the parasitic losses. The losses from the diode on VBUS are fine since it won't be from the battery.

Thanks guys

[image: Schematic]

Comment: I don't see what Q2 is bringing to the party. Have you tried simulating the circuit? If not, why not?

Comment: You can get "ideal diode" ICs that are designed specifically to handle this situation.

Comment: @Andyaka Q2 prevents the USB 5V from directly (over)charging the battery.

Comment: @Andyaka Cristobol Polychronopolis is exactly right. Without Q2, VBUS voltage would conduct through the body diode of Q1 and charge the non rechargeable battery causing a hazard.

Comment: OK guys I see that now! So, why Q1 then? Why not just a short?

Comment: @Andyaka When Q1 and Q2 are off, VBUS voltage will conduct through the body diode of Q1, but the body diode of Q2 will block it, keeping the battery from being charged. Q1 & Q2 are the exact same PFETs with sources tied together. You could easily just replace Q2 with a regular diode and preserve the same function, but in this case, the parasitic loses from a normal diode would be too high for this application, that is why I am using a PFET in place of a diode.

Comment: I see no issue.

Comment: So, what does Q1 bring to the party?

Comment: Agree with @Andyaka. Not really sure why Q1 is needed.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm sorry, I just realized I talked more about Q2 in the answer above. When this device is plugged into a computer,  Q2 will turn off. Without Q1, The battery will still partially power the load along with VBUS. This is all about maximizing battery life. Keep in mind, VBUS is not 5V, it is raw USB voltage regulated to 3-3.3v. The battery is 3.6v. After the voltage drop VBUS takes across the diode, its now sending about 2.8v to the load. With a battery at 3.6-3.7v, it would certainly unnecessarily reduce battery life. No telling how long a customer may leave USB powered on

Comment: How will Q1 power the VBUS given that you have diode D1 blocking it?

Comment: @Andyaka VBUS is not powered from Q1. VBUS is a separate power supply as shown in the schematic. Q1's purpose is to block the battery from powering the load when USB is applied

Comment: I see, since VBUS is actually lower than the battery's voltage, the Q2's body diode would be forward-biased in the absence of Q1—when you are not driving Q2. Story would be different if VBUS were actually 5V, as I assumed, then that diode would be reverse-biased and now current would not flow when Q2 is OFF.

Comment: @Big6 I'm not sure what you mean. Voltage doesn't change the diode direction. Even  if VBUS were 5v, it still wouldn't work in this topology. 5v VBUS would give Q2 Vgs -1.7v which would turn it on and potentially over charge the battery. To make this work, Q2's gate would have to be tied to VBUS, not to a limited interface output as it currently is.

Comment: I didn't mean that the diode direction would change, but if you drive the gate of Q2 high, say 3.3V, then in the presence of VBUS (also 3.3V), Q2 is off but its body diode may still leak current from the battery to the load. That is the case because the voltage at the anode of the body diode is Vbat ~3.6V and the voltage at its cathode is VBUS-VD1= ~2.8V, so the body diode is forward biased. In this condition, you do have a leakage current flowing from the battery, through Q2's body diode, to the load. All of this in the absence of Q1. That's why I said that I could then see the need for Q1.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the turning-off voltage of the PMOSFETs "independent" of their rated \$V_{TH}\$, you can use a circuit similar to the following:

[image: Circuit]
[image: Waveforms]
Transition is made after 1ms. You can reduce the forward voltage drop of the diode by using a schottky one. An output capacitor might be necessary if you want to overcome, or at least reduce the voltage drop which occurs during the transition.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! However, this is unnecessary for the given application and adds too many components to the design. But I do love this simulator! The one I'm using isn't this advanced. What is it?

Comment: It is a free software called LTspice (https://www.analog.com/en/design-center/design-tools-and-calculators/ltspice-simulator.html)